# How to read uncommit data in same transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I have one method do and call inside other method userupdate. inside method userupdate() first i have got user entity from database and after data change its name . Now i try to get user entity of same user id inside do method but got successfully but issue is that i have got old user name no new update username . I have tried this with isolation level READ_UNCOMMITTED .

```
      Transactional( isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
      public void do(){
      User user = getUser( userId );
      print(user.getName());//print old name Anuj
   }

private void userupdate( userId ){
  User user = finduserOnbaseUserId(userId);
  user.setName("updatedName");
}
```

Please one help me how can a get update user entity inside do(). Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got reasons why this not works because spring can not intercept method call of same class so transaction not apply in this case . There is need new bean for update method and inject in this class then code running successfully i have refer this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring)